# Undefined reference в классе с Template

Tags: c++, шаблоны-с++, системное-программирование

Allocator.pro

```
TEMPLATE = app
CONFIG += console c++17
CONFIG -= app_bundle
CONFIG -= qt

SOURCES += \
        main.cpp \
    allocuser.cpp

HEADERS += \
    allocuser.h
```

allocuser.h

```
#ifndef ALLOCUSER_H
#define ALLOCUSER_H

#include <bitset>
using namespace std;

class AllocUser
{
private:
public:
    AllocUser();
    const static int maxItem = 1000;
    const static int maxSize = 32;

    static std::bitset<maxItem> bufmap;
    static inline char buf[maxItem * maxSize];
    static int freeblock;

    template <typename T>
        static T *allocate(void) {
                int i;
                static_assert( sizeof(T) < AllocUser::maxSize, "Max size for this allocator excessed " );
                    for(i=AllocUser::freeblock; i<AllocUser::maxItem; i++) {
                            if( !AllocUser::bufmap.test(i) )
                                break;
                }
                if( i==AllocUser::maxItem ) throw new bad_alloc();
                AllocUser::bufmap.set(i, true);
                AllocUser::freeblock=i+1;
                return static_cast<T*> (new (&buf[AllocUser::maxSize*i]) T());
        }
    template <typename T>
        static void deallocate(T *ptr) {
                int i = ( ((char*)ptr)-&buf[0] )/maxSize;
  //              if( !bufmap.test(i) ) throw new logic_error("Wrong deallocate");
                ptr->~T();
                bufmap.set(i, false);
                if( freeblock > i ) freeblock=i;
        }

};
#endif // ALLOCUSER_H
```

allocuser.cpp

```
#include "allocuser.h"
using namespace std;

AllocUser::AllocUser()
{
std::bitset<maxItem> bufmap;
}
```

main.cpp

```
#include <iostream>
#include <allocuser.h>
#define MAX_SZ 32
#define MAX_ITEM 1000
using namespace std;

int AllocUser::freeblock=0;

int main()
{
    cout << "Hello World!" << endl;

 //   AllocUser *allocu = new AllocUser ();
  //  int allocu->freeblock=0;
    for(long i=0; i<1000; i++) {
        for(int j=0; j<3; j++){
            int *a = AllocUser::allocate<int>();
            *a=5;
            AllocUser::deallocate( a );
        }
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Интересно - ошибка **только** для `bufmap`?

Comment: нет, ещё для buf

Comment: А почему же вы не даете **всю** информацию?..

Comment: @Harry там тоже самое. На мой взгляд это и была вся информация.

Comment: Ключевое слово - "*на ваш взгляд*". К доктору вы тоже так ходите? :)

Comment: @Harry само собой так же, я же не доктор чтобы иметь нужную квалификацию для обнаружения нестандартного поведения моего организма. Так же и здесь, пользуясь своим уровнем квалификации определяю нужные параметры без лишнего для решения проблемы. Сколько помню, на форумах такое отношение приветствуется в первую очередь.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Не вижу никакого отношения к какому-то "Template" - ваш класс шаблонным не является. Как обычно в большинстве таких случаев, в вашем коде нет определения `std::bitset<maxItem> bufmap;`.

Либо добавьте определение в `.cpp` файле

```
std::bitset<maxItem> AllocUser::bufmap;
```

Либо (более простой вариант исправления) - прямо в определении класса сделайте

```
static inline std::bitset<maxItem> bufmap;
```

То же относится и ко всем остальным статическим полям, кроме, возможно, `const int` полей.

---

Также не ясно, зачем вы применяете `static_cast<T*>` к указателю, который и так уже имеет тип `T *`.

Comment: /home/alexandr/programming/allocator/Allocator/allocuser.h:16: предупреждение: inline variables are only available with -std=c++1z or -std=gnu++1z
Второй вариант не сработал. Первый выдал     std::bitset<maxItem> AllocUser::bufmap; qualified-id in declaration before ‘;’ token

Comment: У меня было предположение, что проблема с тем что в templeate-структуре нет определения.

Comment: 1. Ну так почему вы не пользуетесь C++17? На это есть причины? Если на это есть причины, то вы сами должны их озвучивать. 2. Определение `std::bitset<maxItem> AllocUser::bufmap;` надо делать там, где *видно исходное определение класса*. Обязательно видно исходное определение класса. Вы, очевидно, засунули это куда-то, где определение не видно. Не надо так делать. 3. О какой "templeate-структуре" вы ведете речь? У вас в коде не видно никакой "templeate-структуры".

Comment: включил поддержку с++17 второй вариант сразу заработал. Про первый вариант не совсем понятно, прописал в инициализаторе класса получил /home/alexandr/programming/allocator/Allocator/allocuser.h:25: ошибка: ‘bufmap’ is not a member of ‘AllocUser’
                             if( !AllocUser::bufmap.test(i) )

Comment: @shaman888: Я не знаю, как вам удалось добиться такой ошибки. То, что написано в первом варианте, надо сделать *в дополнение* к вашему изначальному коду, а не *вместо* него. А вы, похоже, убрали объявление `bufmap` из `AllocUser`. Не надо его оттуда убирать.

Comment: вернул как в заголовке, и добавил в инициализатор первый вариант. Ошибка та же. /home/alexandr/programming/allocator/Allocator/allocuser.h:25: ошибка: undefined reference to `AllocUser::bufmap'

Comment: @shaman888: Ну, я не знаю, что сказать. Отсюда не видно, что вы там такое написали и как вам удается получить такую ошибку.

Comment: обновил вопрос, выложил код целиком.

Comment: @shaman888: Ну и какое отношение это имеет к первому способу? Во-первых, должно быть написано `std::bitset<maxItem> AllocUser::bufmap;`, как у меня в ответе. Именно так, буква в букву. Где в вашем коде такое? Во-вторых, определение статического члена должно быть сделано на уровне namespace. т.е. *на уровне файла*, а не внутри функции.

Comment: У вас в коде уже есть совершенно правильное определение для `int AllocUser::freeblock=0;`, которое почему-то болтается в `main.cpp`. Почему вы не в состоянии точно так же сделать определение для `std::bitset<maxItem> AllocUser::bufmap;`?

Comment: был невнимателен к <AllocUser::maxItem>